# C# Unity, Changing Array button colour only last array being affected when added OnClick.Addlistener

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public GameObject SongListParent; // Dragged from the inpsector

private GameObject SongListButton;
private GameObject SongListPrefab

private Object[] myMusic;

void awake(){

for(int i = 0; i < myMusic.Length; i++ ) {

    int TempInt = i;

    //Instantiate the song list
    SongListButtons = (Resources.Load("Prefabs/Button")) as GameObject;

    SongListPrefab = (GameObject) Instantiate(SongListButtons);
    SongListPrefab.transform.SetParent(SongListParent.transform, false);

    //setting the label
    datext = SongListPrefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
    datext[0].text = myMusic.name;

    //Adding Function and positioning
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3(10, i*-30, 0);
    SongListPrefab.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = pos;
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = myMusic as AudioClip;
    SongListPrefab.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => lol(TempInt) );

};

}

public void lol(int buttonNo){
//Play Audio Onclick
GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = myMusic[buttonNo] as AudioClip;
GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

//Change Color Onclick, << Problem starts here only the last array gets coloured
Image[] lel = SongListPrefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
lel[0].color = Color.red;
}
```

When i run the code only the last array of the button prefab gets coloured when clicked, i have tried putting lel[buttonNo].color instead of lel[0].color but after i clicked the button but it says array out of range. What i am trying to achieve here is when the button is clicked the button is colored, but in this case when i click any of the buttons it colors the last button in the array. any ideas or suggestion would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Well, the direct problem is that `SongListPrefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();` doesn't return the elements you expect. A better way to do this would be to include the `AudioSource`, `Music`, and the `Image` (or maybe the `GameObject` that contains the `Image`) in the handler closure, rather than just one `int`.

Comment: @31eee384 thank you for your respond and yes i just noticed that was the problem, i have changed it by making `SongListPrefab.GetComponent<Button>();` as a variable called button, then passing it to `button.onClick.AddListener(() => lol(TempInt, button));` in the lol function it had `public void lol(int buttonNo, Button button)` then added inside the function `button.image.color = Color.red;`, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
Image[] lel = SongListPrefab.GetComponentsInChildren<Image>();
```

In loop you reassign the value of `SongListPrefab` to last instantiated prefab:

```
SongListPrefab = (GameObject) Instantiate(SongListButtons);
```

Therefore, `SongListPrefab` will always be the last instantiated GameObject from `SongListButtons`.

The easiest way would probably be to just pass Button to `lol` function and change its color like this:

```
public void Awake()
{
    // previous code
        var button = SongListPrefab.GetComponent<Button>();
        if (button != null)
            button.onClick.AddListener(() => lol(TempInt, button));
}

public void lol(int buttonNo, Button button)
{
    //Play Audio Onclick
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip = myMusic[buttonNo] as AudioClip;
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();

    //Change Color Onclick, << Problem starts here only the last array gets coloured
    button.image.color = Color.red;
}
```

If you really want to have information of every `SongListPrefab` that has been instantiated, you should think of storing all the instantiated `GameObject`s in an array or `List<GameObject>` and then just `.Add()` them to it, then access it by index in `lol()`, although it might be not error-proof later on.

Also you might think of making and additional script just for Button behaviour and attach it in `Inspector` to `onClick` if it's an option.